# How to escape the html using golang?

Tags: go

The html text following:

```
&lt;script type=&#34;text/javascript&#34;&gt;alert(123);&lt;/script&gt;
<script>alert(123);</script>
```

As mentioned above, only part of html text was escaped.

Now, I want to escape the text: **`<script>alert(123);</script>`**.

Expected result:

```
&lt;script type=&#34;text/javascript&#34;&gt;alert(123);&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script&gt;alert(123);&lt;/script&gt;
```

I need some help.

Comment: Please explain what you did and what you're trying to achieve. The example is unclear.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's EscapeString function in html package

```
unescaped := `<script>alert(123);</script>`
escaped := html.EscapeString(unescaped)
```

Comment: It's simply `import "html"`

Answer (score 6):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html"
)

func main() {
    var s string = `"<script>alert(123);</script>"`
    
    fmt.Println(html.EscapeString(s))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say this is an group name column there could be ' or " in the group name right how to we escape just html and not this valid characters, in this case say Fresher's is the group name it would be Fresher[something]s the html.EscapeString() will not work

Comment: It does work perfectly fine with escaping any character, including `"` and `'`:  https://goplay.space/#aW8SePpZHRS